# Elasticsearch: Cannot add documents to an index

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Using tweepy and elasticsearch Python modules I can create the index, but the documents do not get created/added.  I've taken the code from an example that worked for the author (isn't that always the case).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
import tweepy
import sys
import json
from textwrap import TextWrapper
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

consumer_key = "abcd"
consumer_secret = "1234"
access_token = "qwerty-5678"
access_secret = "huffalump"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

es = Elasticsearch()

#es.indices.create(index="twitter", ignore=400)

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
status_wrapper = TextWrapper(width=60, initial_indent='    ', subsequent_indent='    ')

    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            print 'n%s %s' % (status.author.screen_name, status.created_at)

            json_data = status._json
            print json_data['text']

            es.create(index="twitter", doc_type="twitter_twp", body=json_data)

        except Exception, e:
            print e
            pass

streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth, listener=StreamListener(), timeout=3000000000 )

#Fill with your own Keywords below
terms = ['cyber']

streamer.filter(None,terms)
#streamer.userstream(None)
```

I monitor my Elasticsearch index at http://192.168.1.7:9200/_cat/indices?v and the data never changes:

```
health status index   uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   twitter WDYgTflkRZ-5dTRHx2zuEw   3   2          0            0       390b           390b
```

I've tried everything - even reading the docs.  Why aren't my docs going in my index!?

Comment: It looks like on_status is never called. Or is it supposed to be a method on StreamListener? If so the indentation is off. Can you verify that on_status is actually getting called.

Comment: Exactly, if you want to `on_status` and `status_wrapper` be part of your class you should indent them

Comment: Indentation was wrong in my code example - on_status was being called. Author, created_at, and text was being printed for each tweet